# How do I use graphql-code-generator with Hasura when they expect differently-named query roots?

Tags: graphql, hasura, graphql-codegen

The schemas emitted by Hasura [group queries under a `query_root` type](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/databases/postgres/queries/index.html). But [`graphql-codegen` expects them grouped under a type named `Query`](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/issues/5758). How do people bridge that gap?